# Conditional Formatting row wise

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

There is a cell I want to format if two cells in a row meet conditions:

When cell F4 equals one of the workers and the max. hours of the **same** worker is > 10 cell F4 should be red.

I tried this but didnt get the rule working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula in CF:

```
=SUM(($L$13:$L$15=$F$4)*($M$13:$M$15>10))
```

and apply to range `F4`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

- Mark all the cells you want to be colored IF the rule applies
- Make your rule as it would look for the TOP left cell/row

Look at this example:

[image]

So in this case, i would like the rule for the first row to be: Color red if cell F4 > 10.

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, but I need cell outside Worker and max hours to be highlighted but with the conditions of them.

Comment: Then include those cells in the area you select in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

try worksheet change event. u can easly add borders, font etc
in vbe worksheet with data paste

```
Dim int_fcol, int_frow, int_lcol, int_lrow As Integer
Dim rng_WorkRange As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

int_fcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column
int_frow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row
int_lcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(int_frow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
int_lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, int_fcol).End(xlUp).Row

'MsgBox "first columns is: " & int_fcol & vbCrLf & _
"first row is: " & int_frow & vbCrLf & _
"last column is: " & int_lcol & vbCrLf & _
"last row is: " & int_lrow
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim int_ColumnWithHours As Integer
'   column with hours
int_ColumnWithHours = int_fcol + 1

If Target.Column = int_ColumnWithHours Then
    '   setting table range
    Set rng_WorkRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, int_fcol), ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, int_lcol))
    If Target.Value > 10 Then   '   check does more than 10 hour
        '   if true colour red
        rng_WorkRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else    '   If Target.Value > 10
        '   if false white
        rng_WorkRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If  '   If Target.Value > 10
End If  '   If Target.Column = int_fcol + 1
End Sub
```